# How to get Android Studio to display Square or Round form factor for Wearables as appropriate in the designer panel?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

If I use Android Studio to create a template project for watch development then by default it is displayed as a Nexus 4 in the designer.

Obviously this is completely useless for designing a watch UI so if I select the rect_activity_main.xml layout and change its form factor to be Android Wear Square then it displays as a square watch.
[image]

Great, this is what I want. However when I select round_activity_main.xml that too is displaying as a square:

[image]

If I change that to a circle then switch back to Rect_activity_main.xml now that too is displaying as a circle.

Notice also how they are both saying Hello Round World, it should say Hello Square World or Hello Round World as appropriate.

How can I get it to display a square for rect_activity_main.xml and a circle for round_activity_main.xml?
As there is actually only one MainActivity java class there's nothing else to change the association to.
[image]

I'm using Android Studio v 1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The device that you see on Android Studio's Preview section is merely projecting the XML code onto the selected device i.e. Wear Square.

Android Studio doesn't remember what device was chosen when viewing a particular XML file; it will just show the device you last chose and use it for every XML file you open. By this, I mean that Wear Square will continue to be used when using Preview until you change it.

If you are wondering how to tailor layout files so that they differ for **actual** Wear devices, you should look into using the WatchViewStub class. A good example of this can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchViewStub/index.html).